# iptables: Allow port range but deny to certain IP

Tags: centos, iptables, ip, port

I am running a server which needs UDP ports 1000:11000 opened, as well as TCP 10011 and 30033 open to function.

I have a set of iptables rules set to allow SSH and those ports, and intentionally left out 2010 as I am getting attacked on that port. The server does not block the incoming IP even when told to do so. The IP that needs to be denied is: 194.97.114.3.

My iptables script:

```
service iptables restart
iptables --flush

iptables -P INPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p all -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10011 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30033 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT


iptables -A INPUT -s 194.97.114.3 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --destination-port 1000:2009 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --destination-port 2011:11000 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

With that, 194.97.114.3 is still able to connect on port 2010. Please help me.

*EDIT*, iptables -L -v -N output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 2833 packets, 412K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 305K   26M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:2011:11000
 2910  128K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:1000:2009
  145 19881 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  303 17915 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10011
   41  1816 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:30033
  393 28420 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
    6   216 DROP       all  --  *      *       194.97.114.3         0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 415K packets, 37M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: `iptables -v -L -n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try follow me

```
echo > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
service iptables restart
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport ! --dports 30033,10011,22 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 1000:2009,2011:11000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m multiport -s 194.97.114.3 --dports 1000:2009,2011:11000 -j DROP
```

Comment: I did the above commands, but that IP is still able to connect to the server on port 2010.

Comment: I was just re-reading the logs and realized that the server is connecting to that IP, not being connected to. That IP tables rules are correct, thank you all. I need more sleep. That would explain why my bans weren't working!

Comment: I see your rule can block IP you want, output: 6   216 DROP       all  --  *      *       194.97.114.3         0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 3):

Move your DROP line to before the ACCEPT lines.

Comment: iptables, order matters.

Comment: I did, that still is allowing the IP to connect.

Comment: @CollinBiedenkapp: Then you did it wrong.

Comment: @CollinBiedenkapp, the config you posted clearly shows the DROP listed after the ACCEPTs. Quite simply, the DROP line would not get executed for a port 22 access because you've already told it to let everyone through.

Comment: I'm beginning to see how sensitive iptables is to order. I didn't realize that at first. I'm a Windows user, where everything is idiot-proof.

Comment: @Colin, if Windows really was idiot-proof many of us wouldn't have a job.

Comment: That's very true.